# Laravel Password reset link not generated in forget_password_submit method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm encountering an issue with generating a password reset link in my Laravel application within the forget_password_submit method. Despite attempting to construct the link using Laravel's URL::to() helper function, the link doesn't seem to be generated correctly. here i used mailtrap for testing mail.

Here's my forget_password_submit method:

```
public function forget_password_submit(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]);

    $admin_data = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if (!$admin_data) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Email address not found!');
    }

    $token = hash('sha256', time());

    $admin_data->token = $token;
    $admin_data->update();

    $reset_link = URL::to('admin/reset-password/' . $token . '/' . $request->email);
    $subject = 'Reset Password';
    $message = 'Please click on the following link: <br>';
    $message .= '<a href="' . $reset_link . '">Click here</a>';

    Mail::to($request->email)->send(new Websitemail($subject, $message));

    return redirect()->route('admin_login')->with('success', 'Please check your email and follow the steps there');
}
```

Despite constructing the link using URL::to(), the link is not being generated as expected. I've ensured that the APP_URL variable in the .env file is correctly set, and my routes are properly defined.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?
Laravel has built-in services for password reset: https://laravel.com/docs/passwords

Comment: What do you mean not generated? is `URL::to()` results to null? How about token and request->email, are they null as well? did you check error logs?